# PHP: preg_replace() on NameSpace

Tags: php, regex, escaping

I'm trying to get the parent "elements" name as string from a PHP namespace in a string, the ideia is to do:

Input: `\Base\Util\Review`; Desired Output: `\Base\Util`;

My main problem here is how can I deal with the backslash escaping in the regex expression, so far I can make it work with the normal slash:

```
$ns = "/Base/Util/Review";
print preg_replace("#\/[^/]*$#", '', $ns);
// Outputs => /Base/Util
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$s = '\\Base\\Util\\Review';
$r = preg_replace('~\\\\[^\\\\]*$~', '', $s);
//=> \Base\Util
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without `preg_replace`

```
$ns = "\Base\Util\Review";
print implode('\\', array_slice(explode('\\',$ns),0,-1));
```

Another option:

```
$ns = "\Base\Util\Review";
print substr($ns,0,strrpos($ns,'\\'));
```

Comment: I had something similiar this on my code as a temporary fix. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
print preg_replace("#\\\[^\\\]*$#", '', $ns)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write four backslashes for each literal backslash:

```
$regex = '#\\\\#'; // regex matching one backslash
```

You need to escape each `\` once to escape its special meaning in the regex, and again escape each `\` once to escape its meaning in the PHP string literal.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in detail!